# Making decoder model for sequence to sequence autoencoder in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm working with this example but am confused on how to make the separate decoder model.

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
```

I understand how to make the encoder, but how do we make a separate decoder? I can define all the layers and make the encoder and decoder separately but is there a simpler way to do it like we've done with the encoder model?

Comment: You could try just: `decoder = Model(encoder.output,decoded)` (Never tried this, but I'll add an answer with what I know that works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the encoder:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
```

Create the decoder:

```
decInput = Input((the shape of the encoder's output))    
decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(decInput)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoder = Model(decInput,decoded)
```

Joining models:

```
joinedInput = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoderOut = encoder(joinedInput)    
joinedOut = decoder(encoderOut)
sequence_autoencoder = Model(joinedInput,joinedOut)
```